# Converting TD Ameritrade's JSON API output into Pandas dataframe

Tags: json, dataframe, type-conversion

Python beginner here. Recently connected to my TD Ameritrade's API and tried to extract my account's position information for further analysis. However, I am having trouble converting the API's JSON output into a Pandas dataframe, any guidance would be much appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
import pprint
import pandas as pd
from config import consumer_key, redirect_uri, credentials_path
from td.client import TDClient

# Create a new instance of the client
td_client = TDClient(client_id = consumer_key, redirect_uri = redirect_uri, credentials_path = credentials_path)

# Login to a new session
td_client.login()

# Positions and Orders for an account or account(s)
positions = td_client.get_accounts(account = 'all', fields = ['positions'])
pprint.pprint(positions)
```

Here is a snippet of the output:

```
{'securitiesAccount': {'accountId': 'xxxx',
                       'currentBalances': {'accruedInterest': 0.0,
                                           'bondValue': 0.0,
                                           'cashAvailableForTrading': xxx,
                                           'cashAvailableForWithdrawal': xxx,
                                           'cashBalance': 0.0,
                                           'cashCall': 0.0,
                                           'cashDebitCallValue': 0.0,
                                           'cashReceipts': 0.0,
                                           'liquidationValue': xxx,
                                           'longMarketValue': xxx,
                                           'longNonMarginableMarketValue': xxx,
                                           'longOptionMarketValue': 0.0,
                                           'moneyMarketFund': xxx,
                                           'mutualFundValue': 0.0,
                                           'pendingDeposits': 0.0,
                                           'savings': 0.0,
                                           'shortMarketValue': 0.0,
                                           'shortOptionMarketValue': 0.0,
                                           'totalCash': 0.0,
                                           'unsettledCash': 0.0},
                       'initialBalances': {'accountValue': xxx,
                                           'accruedInterest': 0.0,
                                           'bondValue': 0.0,
                                           'cashAvailableForTrading': xxx,
                                           'cashAvailableForWithdrawal': xxx,
                                           'cashBalance': 0.0,
                                           'cashDebitCallValue': 0.0,
                                           'cashReceipts': 0.0,
                                           'isInCall': False,
                                           'liquidationValue': xxx,
                                           'longOptionMarketValue': 0.0,
                                           'longStockValue': xxx,
                                           'moneyMarketFund': xxx,
                                           'mutualFundValue': 0.0,
                                           'pendingDeposits': 0.0,
                                           'shortOptionMarketValue': 0.0,
                                           'shortStockValue': 0.0,
                                           'unsettledCash': 0.0},
                       'isClosingOnlyRestricted': False,
                       'isDayTrader': False,
                       'positions': [
                                     {'averagePrice': 46.14,
                                      'currentDayProfitLoss': -8.4,
                                      'currentDayProfitLossPercentage': -1.92,
                                      'instrument': {'assetType': 'EQUITY',
                                                     'cusip': '02209S103',
                                                     'symbol': 'MO'},
                                      'longQuantity': 10.0,
                                      'maintenanceRequirement': 0.0,
                                      'marketValue': 429.4,
                                      'settledLongQuantity': 10.0,
                                      'settledShortQuantity': 0.0,
                                      'shortQuantity': 0.0},
                                     {'averagePrice': 152.14,
                                      'currentDayProfitLoss': -1.52,
                                      'currentDayProfitLossPercentage': -0.43,
                                      'instrument': {'assetType': 'EQUITY',
                                                     'cusip': '88579Y101',
                                                     'symbol': 'MMM'},
                                      'longQuantity': 2.0,
                                      'maintenanceRequirement': 0.0,
                                      'marketValue': 351.32,
                                      'settledLongQuantity': 2.0,
                                      'settledShortQuantity': 0.0,
                                      'shortQuantity': 0.0},
                                ],
                       'projectedBalances': {'cashAvailableForTrading': xxx,
                                             'cashAvailableForWithdrawal': xxx},
                       'roundTrips': 0,
                       'type': 'CASH'}}
```

How can I convert this into a dataframe with only the information about the positions? (For example, a dataframe with each stock I own as an individual row).

I've tried the following code, but it does not return the desired results:

```
df = pd.json_normalize(positions)
print(positions)
```

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might get confusing to call your response 'positions' and then go look for that key, but nonetheless you need to use the full path to the positions key.

```
pd.json_normalize(positions['securitiesAccount']['positions'])
```

Output

```
   averagePrice  currentDayProfitLoss  currentDayProfitLossPercentage  longQuantity  maintenanceRequirement  marketValue  settledLongQuantity  settledShortQuantity  shortQuantity instrument.assetType instrument.cusip instrument.symbol
0        46.140                -8.400                          -1.920        10.000                   0.000      429.400               10.000                 0.000          0.000               EQUITY        02209S103                MO
1       152.140                -1.520                          -0.430         2.000                   0.000      351.320                2.000                 0.000          0.000               EQUITY        88579Y101               MMM
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always segregate your data by creating a new_dict.

new_dict = (dictionary['securitiesAccount']['positions'])